# Invocation of ViewDidLoad after initWithNibName

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

It appears that `ViewDidLoad()` is sent to a ViewController only after its View is physically displayed (i.e. via NavigationController pushViewController), and not immediately after `initWithNibName()`. Is this a behavior I can rely on? I would like to get the chance to set the member variables of my view so that all the members are valid by the time `ViewDidLoad()` is invoked.

Comment: Why not do that at the start of `ViewDidLoad:`? (Minor nit-pick: `viewDidLoad:` and `initWithNibName:` are methods, not functions. It is conventional to use `:` to denote them, not `()`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set up member variables and other such things in [initWithNibName:bundle:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW15).

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle]) {
        // set up ivars and other stuff here.
        someIvar = someValue;
    }
    return self;
}
```

You are correct that viewDidLoad: is only sent when the view is physically displayed, i.e when it is added to some visible view (which may sometimes be never if the user does not reach that view). So it's useful to split the functionality and think about what you can do at init time and what happens at view load time.

As Marcelo Cantos notes in the comment, viewDidLoad: is generally a fine place to do all sorts of setup work, using the concept of "lazy loading," so that you defer the setup until as late time as possible.

Comment: awakeFromNib can also be a very convenient point for initialization, guaranteed after nib loading is complete.

Comment: Also consider overriding viewWillAppear if your variables need to be initialized every time the view *appears* (rather than just when it is loaded)

Comment: I have found that in Swift, viewDidLoad is (or is sometimes) called directly after super.init. I found this because I filled an array after super.initWithNiBName and viewDidLoad crashed.

Answer (score 3):

`viewDidLoad` is called before a view controller is displayed for the first time, not immediately after `initWithNibName`.  For example, if you have a tab bar controller, all of the child view controllers will be `init`d at launch, but `viewDidLoad` will only be called when you click on the appropriate tab the first time.  It's generally a good idea to initialize memory-intensive items in `viewDidLoad`, so as to avoid using unnecessary memory.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I override initiWithNibName in the view controller, the viewDidLoad method is not called. I have to call it manually [self viewDidLoad]. But if I do not override initWithNibName: viewDidLoad is called. I am working with 4 view controllers in tab bar controller. the tab bar controller is loaded from another view.

Comment: I'm having similar problems. Did you found why is that so?

Comment: Just add [self viewDidLoad] add the end of your initWithNibName method!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to unearth an old thread, but this solved it for me...

-(void)viewDidLoad is only called after -(void)loadView has done its thing. In the docs for loadView:

> The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil.

My view controller only has viewDidLoad called after its view is request by a UITabBarItem, meaning viewDidLoad is only called in the viewController once the tab bar button is pressed. I, like the OP, want viewDidLoad to be called directly after the nib is loaded, so it's contents (titles, etc) can be populated before the user clicks the tab button.

So, after calling "self = [super initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];" in the view controller's custom initialiser, I immediately called '[self view]' afterwards. As the view is requested earlier than when it is requested by the UITabBarItem (which calls 'addSubview'), the view is initialised fully during initialisation, rather than when requested.

Hope this helps.